# GZipStream сжимает со степенью сжатия -150%

Tags: c#, zip

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Понадобилось мне сжимать файлы. Использовал пример с MSDN для шарпа 3.5:

```
                    using (var origStream = new FileStream(info.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
                    using (var destStream = new FileStream(info.TempFullName + ".gz", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) {
                        using (var compressor = new GZipStream(destStream, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
                            var buffer = new byte[origStream.Length];
                            var count = origStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            compressor.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Сжимает медленно довольно. Открываю результат, вижу: оригинальный файл - 1.7мб, "сжатый" файл - 2.8мб. В винраре смотрю - процент сжатия 150%.

Формат файлов на данный момент - PDF.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Сожмите тот же файл оригинальным гзипом и сравните.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такое вполне может случиться, если вы сжимаете маленькую картинку (jpeg) или музыку (mp3), в общем, любой файл, который уже пожат.
Допишите, какой тип файла вы сжимаете.

Comment: ну, сейчас в качестве тестовых файлов использую PDF, в дальнейшем будут спользоваться архивы от UnrealEngine - upk, которые тоже немного пережаты уже.

Проблема в другом - если я эту pdf сжимаю винраром на среднем сжатии, то получается размер файла 1.4мб.
Тоесть сжатие фактически не должно раздувать файл, как минимум оставить такой же размер, ну максимум добавить пару килобайт на технические расходы формата...

Comment: По коду вроде все в порядке.

Comment: zip сжимается похуже, но тоже файл меньше получается, чем оригинальный.

Comment: Так. Бред какой-то. Перевел проект на .NET 4.0, использовал нативное копирование из потока в поток, получил небольше сжатие:

origStream.CopyTo(compressor);

Из 1.7мб в 1.5 мб.
Получается, что-то не так с копированием?

Comment: Да экранирование какое-нибудь случилось. Откройте первый 2.8-МБ файл hex-viewer'ом, там наверняка какие-нибудь слэши двойные и \r

Comment: В Net 4.0 добавили буфер по умолчанию в GZipStream. В предыдущих версиях для достижения аналогичного эффекта следует оборачивать сжимающий поток в BufferedStream.